# Connecting to wifi using wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have some problems connecting to my WiFi (WPA2, standard settings) using `wpa_supplicant`. My `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` is as follows:

```
network={
    ssid="MYWIFI"
    psk=********
}
```

then my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

After putting `wpa_supplicant -D -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` into the console I get a connection, it says:

> Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant.

But there is no connection. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `wlan0` instance to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

For WPA2 I have a few more lines in the wpa configuration file:

```
network={
ssid="myssid"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="verrysecretpw"
}
```

I don't need to bring up the interface manually from the console, it just connects upon booting the system.